'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json

System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=8.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'

Here I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, latest version 2.1.18 that is available in NuGet. But in error it's showing Version=8.0.0.0

What version of dotnet are you using? Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json - this package has been deprecated

Why do you want to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json in the first place? It's almost certain you don't need it. Are you trying to migrate some old ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core project to ASP.NET Core 8 ? That package was deprecated in .NET Core 3.0

I am trying to migrate from .Net Core WebApi 2.1 project to .Net Core WebApi  8.0

this can happen due to version conflicts or missing dependencies for kindly check following
#1 check your csproj file and ensure that there are no conflicting versions for the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json
#2 if there is any existing dependencies for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json then remove the dependency.
